# Why are so few inclined circumbinary planets known?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, stability

For a research project I'm studying the orbits of [circumbinary planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumbinary_planet), most of these planets orbits are coplanar. However I was wondering if orbits with a high inclination could be stable. I made a model for gravity and fiddled around with the equations for planetary motion but these orbits seem stable to me, how can it be that so few have been found?

Is my assumption these orbits are stable wrong or is the way exoplanets are discovered biased to coplanar orbits?

Comment: Good questiin. A high inclination orbit may be stable, but I suspect the probability is low for a planet (big enough to be detectable) to acquire the necessary angular momentum for such an orbit.

Comment: You could ask on [astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=circumbinary).